# Unit tests (gtest?) for C++ Builder VCL application

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, googletest

I am trying to prepare environment to create unit tests for C++ Borland Builder (XE2) application.
My first choice was gtest.
I am able to write tests for classes which are not related to VCL forms.
Problems started when I wanted to write tests for class which include VCL classes, for example:

```
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
```

Did someone know how to compile such class?
I am using Cygwin and basic Makefile like:
http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn@703/trunk/make/Makefile.
I have access to Vcl.StdCtrls.dcu, but I am not sure if it is possible to use *.dcu files in gtest.
Do you have any experience with writing unit tests for such application?

Thank you in advance,
Rafał

Comment: Not used Borland in a long long time. Does stdctrls have  code for widgets (buttons, comboboxes, etc.) in it? If so you should not be testing code that could rely on iteraction or display. For instance to test a class that updated a progress bar, we used dependency injection to use a proper progress bar but for unittesting we had a neutered one that did nothing.

Comment: Hi, yes, I am including StdCtrl to use TComboBox class. Maybe I will try to create some almost empty stubs to just test other methods.
I would like to ask about one more, related thing. All those VCL class use AnsiString. I have in my code many methods which operate on that string (for ex. remove some special characters).
I need to include system.hpp to build that code. In Builder folder I have found System.AnsiString.pas/duc (which probably will do not help me), but in lib/win32/ there is System.obj, there is any way to link it in my Makefile?

Comment: I am unable to answer that that as I haven't used Borland in a long time.  You should only be testing your own code. When I work with UI through MFC I tend to use Microsoft constructs (CString, etc) but everywhere else run straight C++. There are some ugly edge cases but in the long run working on keeping that separation pays off in unit testing.